# understanding leetCode - 121. Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand a solution that I found for the following leetCode problem.

Description:
"You are given an array of prices where prices[i] is the price of a given stock on the ith day.
You want to maximize your profit by choosing a single day to buy one stock and choosing a different day in the future to sell that stock.
Return the maximum profit you can achieve from this transaction. If you cannot achieve any profit, return 0. "

Explanation:
"Input: prices = [7,1,5,3,6,4]
Output: 5
Explanation: Buy on day 2 (price = 1) and sell on day 5 (price = 6), profit = 6-1 = 5.
Note that buying on day 2 and selling on day 1 is not allowed because you must buy before you sell."

And I came across this solution that I'm trying to understand. Breaking it down at "->":

```
def max_profit([7,1,5,3,6,4])
  value = 0
  profit = 0

  (1...prices.size).each do |i|
    value += (prices[i] - prices[i-1])
```

-> So here value = 0 + (1-7 = -6)= -6 /value = -6 + (5-1=4)= -2 / value = -2+(3-5)=-4 and so on ending in -3

```
    value = [0, value].max
```

-> This is what I don't get. Now value = [0, value].max and when I print it I get 0,4,2,5,3.

The way I'm seeing this is:
(in the first iteration) value = [0, -6].max, so value is 0 because 0 > than -6

but then I get 4 for the second iteration when  value = [0, -2].max ... Shouldn't it be 0 again?? How am  getting 0,4,2,5,3 ???

What actually happens when I do value = [0, value].max. ?

```
profit = value if value > profit
  end

  profit
end
```

A million thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to understand a program is to simply step through it with pen and paper, while keeping track of all the (relevant) state. So, let's do just that.

In our case, the relevant state are the values of the two local variables `profit` and `value` as well as the iteration variable `i` and by extension `prices[i]` and `prices[i-1]`. We start out with both of them being initialized to the value `0` in lines 1 and 2 of the method. Then, lines 4–8 are the loop which does all the actual work; line 10 simply returns the result. It is easy to see that lines 5–7 are the ones doing all the work, so let's focus on those:

| `i` | line | code | what does it do? | `profit` | `value` | `prices[i]` | `prices[i-1]` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | 5 | `value += (prices[i] - prices[i-1])` | add the price difference to the current value | `0` | `0 -6 = -6` | `7` | `1` |
| `1` | 6 | `value = [0, value].max` | set `value` to the maximum of `0` and its current value, IOW set `value` to `0` if it is negative | `0` | `0` | `7` | `1` |
| `1` | 7 | `profit = value if value > profit` | set `profit` to the maximum of its current value and `value` | `0` | `0` | `7` | `1` |
| `2` | 5 | `value += (prices[i] - prices[i-1])` | add the price difference to the current value | `0` | `0 + 4 = 4` | `1` | `5` |
| `2` | 6 | `value = [0, value].max` | set `value` to the maximum of `0` and its current value, IOW set `value` to `0` if it is negative | `0` | `4` | `1` | `5` |
| `2` | 7 | `profit = value if value > profit` | set `profit` to the maximum of its current value and `value` | `4` | `4` | `1` | `5` |
| `3` | 5 | `value += (prices[i] - prices[i-1])` | add the price difference to the current value | `4` | `4 - 2 = 2` | `5` | `3` |
| `3` | 6 | `value = [0, value].max` | set `value` to the maximum of `0` and its current value, IOW set `value` to `0` if it is negative | `4` | `2` | `5` | `3` |
| `3` | 7 | `profit = value if value > profit` | set `profit` to the maximum of its current value and `value` | `4` | `4` | `5` | `3` |
| `4` | 5 | `value += (prices[i] - prices[i-1])` | add the price difference to the current value | `4` | `2 + 3 = 5` | `3` | `6` |
| `4` | 6 | `value = [0, value].max` | set `value` to the maximum of `0` and its current value, IOW set `value` to `0` if it is negative | `4` | `5` | `3` | `6` |
| `4` | 7 | `profit = value if value > profit` | set `profit` to the maximum of its current value and `value` | `5` | `5` | `3` | `6` |
| `5` | 5 | `value += (prices[i] - prices[i-1])` | add the price difference to the current value | `5` | `5 - 2 = 3` | `6` | `4` |
| `5` | 6 | `value = [0, value].max` | set `value` to the maximum of `0` and its current value, IOW set `value` to `0` if it is negative | `5` | `3` | `6` | `4` |
| `5` | 7 | `profit = value if value > profit` | set `profit` to the maximum of its current value and `value` | `5` | `3` | `6` | `4` |

> What actually happens when I do value = [0, value].max. ?

The easiest way to find out what a method does, is to read [its documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) [note, technically, this method is not `Enumerable#max` but [`Array#max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-max), but they behave the same in this example]:

> Returns the object in *enum* with the maximum value.

So, in other words, the method does what its name suggests: it returns the maximum of the `Enumerable`.

Note that this is not a very idiomatic way to write the code. For example, it makes no sense to use `max` in line 6 and `if` in line 7 to do the same thing: stick to one or the other, do not confuse the reader by using two different things to do the same thing. Also manually iterating over a collection is practically never done in Ruby. This would be much better expressed using [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and e.g. [`Enumerable#max_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) or [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). Actually, the *perfect* solution would be to use a [*prefix sum* aka *scan*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), but unfortunately, that is not available in Ruby's core and standard libraries.

An idiomatic version would look more like this:

```ruby
def max_profit(prices)
  prices.
    each_cons(2).
    reduce([0, 0]) do |(value, profit), (a, b)|
      [[temp = value + b - a, 0].max, [temp, profit].max] 
    do.
    last
end
```

or this:

```ruby
def max_profit(prices)
  prices.
    each_cons(2).
    map {|a, b| b - a }.
    reduce([]) do |res, difference|
      res << [(res[-1] || 0) + difference, 0].max
    end.
    max
end
```

Answer (score 1):

the `#max` method for arrays returns the largest value in an array, so...`[3, 7, 4].max` will return `7` (the largest value)

```
value = [0, value].max
```

This is basically returning whichever is larger (zero or `value`) and assigning it to `value`.  So it replaces any negative quantity in `value` with zero, but leaves it alone if it is a positive value.

Another way to do the same thing...

```
value = 0 if value < 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Note about the condition `you must buy before you sell`, so basically we found the maximum among max profits (each profit `i` is the max among differences between each price[i] and prices after i)

so a naive solution is 2 loops

```
max of [
 max-profit-0: max of p[1] - p[0], p[2] - p[0], ...
 max-profit-1: max of p[2] - p[1], p[3] - p[2], ...
 ....
]
```

but the solution you provide is brilliant, it just need only one loop by taking advantages of below things:

- profit between price 0 and price 2 == p[2] - p[0] == (p[1] - p[0]) + (p[2] - p[1])

  => that is the code `value += (prices[i] - prices[i-1])` do about, it will count the profit between the current date j (current step) and the start date i
  as long as the different still positive.
- in case the sum above is positive at step 1 and 2: `p[1] - p[0] > 0` and `p[1] - p[0] + p[2] - p[1] > 0`, that mean `p[0] < p[1]` and `p[0] < p[2]`, we could conclude that for every `p[j]` after date 2 (j > 2), `p[j] - p[0]` always larger than `p[j] - p[1]` and `p[j] - p[2]`, so we could continue count sum (profit) with the start index 0 and ignore 1 and 2, since this problem's target is finding the MAX, right ?

the code `value = [0, value].max` will return value as long as value is positive, then value keep move on.

- in case the sum above (or profit) is positive at step 1 and negative at step 2: `(p[1] - p[0]) + (p[2] - p[1]) < 0` so `p[2] - p[0] < 0` and `p[1] - p[0] > 0`, that mean `p[2] < p[0]` and `p[0] < p[1]`.
- so we have `p[2] < p[0] < p[1]`, obviously for each price `p[j]` after date 2 (j > 2), `p[j] - p[2]` always larger than `p[j] - p[0]` and `p[j] - p[1]`, and so that we could ignore p[0] and p[1], since this problem's target is finding the MAX, right ?

  That why we could reset `value` to zero to start count profit again
  with the start index 2, now value from the code `value += (prices[i] - prices[i-1])` in the next loop is actually `p[3] - p[2]`, not `p[3] - p[2] + p[2] - p[1]...`, remember that we already cached the maximum profit of the range [0..2].

  That is the code `value = [0, value].max` do about, it'll return 0 if value is <= 0.

```
[7, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4]
 +  - # that mean you sure that profits 
      # between each [5, 3, 6, 4] and [7] always < with [1]
      # so reset with date 1
```

good solution!